# How do WCF RIA Services provide metadata for object validation on the client side?

Tags: silverlight, wcf-ria-services

Is it only code generation in complile-time that does the trick? Or some run-time mechanisms are involved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Validation metadata is provided only by codegen. Silverlight Validation uses MemberInfo.GetCustomAttributes() (in System.Reflection) to determine the metadata and I don't believe there are any ways to plug into that.